# Is it possible to get the pixel length of a string in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I am trying to size a box in Google Slides to the length of a string. I would think that I would need pixel size to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2057720/7215091

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53218561