# Text boundary information in a page element

Tags: google-slides-api

Some colleagues and I are working on the Google Slide Add-On called *Refine*. In this add-on we utilize the google slide API. To improve our product we are in need of detailed information of the position of the text within a box. Sometimes the text boundaries are outside of the actual page element (see figure 1), and other times it is within the boundaries of the page element *overflowing*(see figure 2).
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmSnm.png)
[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd6dj.png)

What we would highly appreciate is data points on the text boundaries, see figure 3 and 4 for an example of what kind of boundary information we would like. The boundaries we would like information about are the dashed lines.
[Figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYCAr.png)
[Figure 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/162jP.png)

We've looked a lot into the api documentation but could not find any place this data points. It is natural for us to think that this could be part of [TextRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range), but as we understand it this service is currently missing.

We would highly appreciate this feature and I would love to give you some more information if wanted. With this feature in place, we are able to increase the value offering of our add-on a lot.

Comment: You should create a Feature Request in Google's Issue Tracker, where these questions will be addressed, and you can communicate more about the idea too. I looked for the template to file Slides API feature requests. Here it is: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191598&template=823918

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218561/how-do-you-tell-whether-text-fits-within-its-bounding-shape https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998706/is-it-possible-to-get-the-pixel-length-of-a-string-in-google-apps-script