# Google Slide API script updateShapeProperties autofit

Tags: google-slides-api

Getting error "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to slides.presentations.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[3].updateShapeProperties: Invalid field: autofit_type"

but I think my code is right:

```
'updateShapeProperties': {
  'objectId': pageElementId,
    'fields': 'autofitType',
    'shapeProperties': {
    'autofit': {
      'autofitType':'SHAPE_AUTOFIT'
    }
  }
}
```

Any help much appreciated
Cheers
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that the error message means that the value of `fields` is not correct. In your script, how about modifying as follows.

#### From:

```
'fields': 'autofitType',
```

#### To:

```
'fields': 'autofit.autofitType',
```

#### Note:

- But, in the current stage, it seems that the value of `autofitType` can only use `NONE`. So, when `SHAPE_AUTOFIT` and `TEXT_AUTOFIT` is used for `autofitType`, an error of `Autofit types other than NONE are not supported.` occurs. Please be careful this.

  - About this, it seems that this is not reported as the future request in the issue tracker. So how about reporting it as the future request? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)
- When you test above modification, please modify `'autofitType':'SHAPE_AUTOFIT'` to `'autofitType':'NONE'`. By this, the request occurs no error.

#### Reference:

- [AutofitType](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes#Page.AutofitType)

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike but why is SHAPE_AUTOFIT listed in the docs if not supported ? https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes#Page.AutofitType

Comment: @Greg Cox Thank you for replying. About your new question of `but why is SHAPE_AUTOFIT listed in the docs if not supported ?`, unfortunately, I'm not sure. I think that this depends on Google side. For example, Slides API is growing now. So this might be been developing while it's the current specification. By this, the error message is clearly returned. But this is just my guess. I deeply apologize I cannot tell you the clear answer for your new question. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. For example, how about reporting it to issue tracker as the future request?

Comment: I have raised this as suggested. Thanks again @Tanaike

Comment: The request is 189153562 and they say it is working as planned. Meaning not at all???

Answer (score 0):

You're using an invalid field as what the error message says.

You can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request) for the available fields that can be used to replace your 'autofitType' field.

Comment: Please give example code that results in autofit to a shape or table cell.

Answer (score 0):

In response to Jason E. response, please see the documented Enum for AutofitType [1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/autofit-type)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Here is the content from the provided link:     Enum AutofitType  
On this page
Properties
The autofit types.

Properties

Property Type Description
UNSUPPORTED Enum An autofit type that is not supported.
NONE Enum Autofit isn't applied.
TEXT_AUTOFIT Enum Shrinks the text on overflow.
SHAPE_AUTOFIT Enum Resizes the shape to fit the text.