# Autofit Changing with Text Replace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I have used several toturials to set up a script for google sheets that takes a row and turns it into a slide with a template I have layed out. In that template I set all text-boxes to shrink text on overflow. When coppied this property remains, however after calling replaceAllText, the textboxes loose this setting and it messes with the visuals.

This is the code I have set up. I want to know how to do this without loosing those properties.

```
const copy = googleSlideTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[0]}, ${row[1]} Card`, destiionFolder);
const slide = SlidesApp.openById(copy.getId());
const image = slide.getSlides()[0].getImages()[0];

slide.replaceAllText('{{cardname}}',row[0]);
slide.replaceAllText('{{cardtype}}',row[1]);
slide.replaceAllText('{{cardstaminatype}}',row[2]);
slide.replaceAllText('{{cardstaminacost}}',row[3]);
slide.replaceAllText('{{cardfluff}}',row[4]);
slide.replaceAllText('{{cardabilitylist}}',row[5]);
slide.replaceAllText('{{cardstaminaatribute}}',row[6]);
slide.replaceAllText('{{cardattackatribute}}',row[7]);
slide.replaceAllText('{{cardprotectionatribute}}',row[8]);
slide.replaceAllText('{{cardpacksymbol}}',row[9]);
image.replace(row[10], true);

slide.saveAndClose();
```

To replace text and not have overflow rules replaced. The overflow rules were replaced. I insured the overflow rules are in the template sheet and my prefrences defualt to those same rules.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to updating the Autofit property here:

[Google Slide API script updateShapeProperties autofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675410/google-slide-api-script-updateshapeproperties-autofit?rq=4)

Maybe you could reverse engineer this and get it to work? I'm very interested because I'm trying to do the same thing.