# Set TextBox AutofillType in google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I would like to set `TextBox`  `AutofillType` using Apps Script. The only thing I found is [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/autofit) `Class Autofill` but it has no setters. Also, something similar is mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218561/how-do-you-tell-whether-text-fits-within-its-bounding-shape) post but the latest answer is 6 months old.

Is it possible to set `AutofillType` using Apps Script?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There still no method in Apps Script of setting the `AutofitType` of the shape. No documentations whatsoever and autofills in Apps Script editor doesn't show one.