# Setting the autofit text property

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I want to set the textbox autofix as shrink to shape,

I dont understand how to set the autofit for existing as SHRINK text on overflow

[image]
I have tried with

```
  Slides.Presentations.Pages[0].get(presentationId, pageObjectId).pageElements[3].shape.shapeProperties.autofit
```

Comment: Autofit types other than NONE are not supported

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you tell whether text fits within its bounding shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218561/how-do-you-tell-whether-text-fits-within-its-bounding-shape)

Answer (score 1):

**You are trying to set the properties of a `shape` by using a `GET` request.**

If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/get) page of the request:

```
GET https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/{presentationId}/pages/{pageObjectId}
```

> Gets the latest version of the specified page in the presentation.

Moreover, the fields you are using are also wrong. `Pages` is part of the request and you **cannot** pass any parameters to it and `pageObjectId` is in fact the id of the page, not the id of the object you are trying to modify.

In order to set the update the shape properties of an object, you will have to make the following request:

```
POST https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/{presentationId}:batchUpdate
```

And use the following body:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateShapeProperties": {
        "objectId": "OBJECT_ID",
        "shapeProperties": {
          "autofit": {
            "autofitType": "AUTOFIT_TYPE"
          }
        },
        "fields": "autofit.autofitType"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**However**, it is important to note the following as it might be the reason you are receiving the `Autofit types other than NONE are not supported` error:

> **The field is automatically set to `NONE` if a request is made that might affect text fitting within its bounding text box**. In this case the `fontScale` is applied to the `fontSize` and the `lineSpacingReduction` is applied to the `lineSpacing`. Both properties are also reset to default values.

This concern has already been raised on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189153562) and you can see that this indeed the intended behavior in this situation. What you can do instead is to file a *feature request* by using the form [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191598&template=823918) and provide all the necessary details.

#### Reference

- [Slides API presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate);
- [Slides API updateShapePropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateshapepropertiesrequest);
- [Slides API presentations.pages.get](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/get).