# Is there a way to use the new Autofit command in google App Script to autoscale text in a textbox?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I am trying to place a textbox within google slides using App Script. The textbox is dimensioned with a set width and height and already contains text inside. Currently, the text is overflowing past the defined bounds of the textbox but I need a way to have the font size shrink dynamically in order to fit everything inside the preset bounds and dimensions of the textbox.

Google's new Autofit feature is interesting but they haven't released documentation on how to use the Autofit feature in App Script. I was wondering if there was a way to code up or use the Autofit feature in App Script.

** I am doing this natively so I would prefer if the code doesn't involve Google App Script API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you tell whether text fits within its bounding shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218561/how-do-you-tell-whether-text-fits-within-its-bounding-shape)

Comment: Do you want to use Apps Script or the Slides API directly? As @Kos mentions in the linked answer, there is a known issue which affects shapes's autofit. You can't autofit into random shapes other that text boxes.